# Use <p:commandLink> just for JS execution without form submit

Tags: jsf, primefaces, commandlink

How can I make `<p:commandLink>` without submit? Just for JS execution.
For `<p:commandButton>` I can do it this way:

```
<p:commandButton value="JS button" type="button" onclick="alert('clicked')"/>
```

What is the analog for `<p:commandLink>`?

Answer (score 19):

Just `return false` from the JavaScript handler.

```
<p:commandLink ... onclick="alert('clicked'); return false;" />
```

The same applies to all other `on*` attributes and the command button, by the way.

```
<p:commandButton ... onclick="alert('clicked'); return false;" />
```

Whenever you `return false` from any JavaScript `on*` attribute on a HTML element, the element's default action/behavior (in this case, submitting the form) will be blocked.

Nonetheless, if you don't need to invoke a JSF backing bean action method after all, just don't use a command link/button component in first place. Use a plain link/button component.

```
<h:link ... onclick="alert('clicked'); return false;" />
```

```
<p:button ... onclick="alert('clicked'); return false;" />
```

Those doesn't need to be placed in a form, too.